# Как писать коментарии в json-конфиге?

Tags: json, config, комментарии

Есть конфиг файл в формате `json`. Нужно закоментировать одну строку и попробовать другое значение. Ну и сопроводиловку для будущего себя накатать. Какой знак за это отвечает?

Comment: Сам по себе json может содержать коментарии(только никто так не делает) зависит от парсера. Лично сталкивался с json содержащим  // или /**/ коментарии.

Comment: Я не про костыли. Я именно про общепринятый стандарт. Понятно, что можно даже синтаксис полностью переделать с парсером вместе. И всем говорить, что это немного другой json.

Comment: В общепринятом стандарте json не предусмотрены комментарии. Однако даже .NET Newtonsoft.Json спокойно их проглатывает - {"key":"value" // comment} не вызовет ошибки парсинга. правда тут стоит понимать что другой парсер может оказаться менее лояльным.

Comment: Именно это я и пытаюсь сказать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `JSON5` завезли комментарии.

`Поддерживаются как однострочные //, так и многострочные /* */ комментарии.`

Источник: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON5

Answer (score 9):

Никак. В json комментарии не предусмотрены. Изначально этот формат разрабатывался для сетевого обмена данными, а уже потом его стали использовать для хранения информации.

Comment: Фекалька, блин ;-(

Answer (score 0):

так удобнее

```
{
    "some-key-comment":"comments_comments",
    "some-key-value":"some-value",
}
```

Comment: Ок, а если прога принимает только те ключи, которые у неё прохардкорены в коде, а на остальное будет валиться с ошибкой? Ты всё читал, что в этом топике написано?